# MySQL On Duplicate Key Update

Tags: mysql, duplicates

It is only allowing me to update resulting in a total of 2

Heres my Table

```
CREATE TABLE `cart` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Product` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quantity` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Quantity` (`Quantity`)
 )
```

Then, my code to insert the data is:

```
$a = '1'

query2 = "      INSERT INTO CART(User, Product,Quantity)
                VALUES
                ('$id','$model_number','$a')
                 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Quantity=Quantity+1";
```

It will work when I Add the data to the database but, upon my second attemp I get this error:

```
Duplicate entry '2' for key 'Quantity'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want this line:

```
  UNIQUE KEY `Quantity` (`Quantity`)
```

That creates a unique constraint on the quantity field, which is why your second insert is failing.  I can't think of any reason why you would want that.

P.S. If you remove that line, make sure to remove the comma (,) from the previous line.

Comment: Was the last statement a joke? That is extremely obvious

Comment: @RPM You would be surprised what's not obvious to many people.

Comment: Or use remove the `UNIQUE` part if you still want to do fast lookups by Quantity.